# Save a DataSet to a database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, transactions

When I load from the database I use one store procedure which loads the `DataItem` and any `Data` associated with it. This comes back in one DataSet with two tables, the first table has one row and describes the `DataItem` and each row in the other table describing the related `Data`.

This DataSet is then used to populate my objects.

My problem comes when I have to save the objects back to the database. I am currently saving the `DataItem` and then looping through all of my `Data` and performing a save on each one. Completely horrible way to go about doing it, I know. It's both slow and it's not transactional.

So what I'd ideally like to do is convert my objects back into my DataSet and then save it all back to the database in one efficient transactional operation. What code do I need on the C# side to make this transactional and to allow me to pass back a DataSet. I presume this will involve using a `TableAdapter`. But given that I have two tables how will this work? What do I use on the SQL side - Can I use store procedures? (I would like to avoid having SQL in my C# project) Would I need to write something that will handle cycling through a datatable to save each record?

What's the best way to go about doing all this? This will form the lynchpin of a project I'm working on so I want it to be as fast and efficient as it can be!

(.NET 4.0 and SQL 2005)

Comment: A simple google search will give you this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: And the related section [__Walkthrough: Saving Data to a Database (Multiple Tables)__](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4esb49b4.aspx)

Comment: Read them prior to posting, maybe I failed to understand. They don't seem to mention what happens on the SQL side. I have read around this, I just wanted some advice on best practice in my situation. Perhaps this isn't the place for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not use TableAdapter in the end as it was more effort than it was worth.

From the comments:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4esb49b4.aspx